# d3.js chart rendering at bottom of wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, d3.js

Why is my js chart rendering at the bottom of the page and not in the body?  I've used tons of these within my site with no problems but this one doesn't seem to want to go where desired.  Thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

www.wcsddata.net/data-topics/jttest/

```
<center><!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
text{
    font-size:12px;
}
.mainBars rect{
  shape-rendering: auto;
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}
.subBars{
    shape-rendering:crispEdges;
}
.edges{
    stroke:none;
    fill-opacity:0.5;
}
.header{
    text-anchor:middle;
    font-size:16px;
}

</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var data=[['Lite','CA',16,0],
['Small','CA',1278,4],
['Medium','CA',27,0],
['Plus','CA',58,0],
['Grand','CA',1551,15],
['Elite','CA',141,0],
['Lite','AZ',5453,35],
['Small','AZ',683,1],
['Medium','AZ',862,0],
['Grand','AZ',6228,30],
['Lite','AL',15001,449],
['Small','AL',527,3],
['Medium','AL',836,0],
['Plus','AL',28648,1419],
['Grand','AL',3,0],
['Lite','CO',13,0],
['Small','CO',396,0],
['Medium','CO',362,0],
['Plus','CO',78,10],
['Grand','CO',2473,32],
['Elite','CO',2063,64],
['Medium','DE',203,0],
['Grand','DE',686,2],
['Elite','DE',826,0],
['Lite','KS',1738,110],
['Small','KS',12925,13],
['Medium','KS',15413,0],
['Small','GA',2166,2],
['Medium','GA',86,0],
['Plus','GA',348,3],
['Grand','GA',4244,18],
['Elite','GA',1536,1],
['Small','IA',351,0],
['Grand','IA',405,1],
['Small','IL',914,1],
['Medium','IL',127,0],
['Grand','IL',1470,7],
['Elite','IL',516,1],
['Lite','IN',43,0],
['Small','IN',667,1],
['Medium','IN',172,0],
['Plus','IN',149,1],
['Grand','IN',1380,5],
['Elite','IN',791,23],
['Small','FL',1,0],
['Grand','FL',1,0],
['Small','MD',1070,1],
['Grand','MD',1171,2],
['Elite','MD',33,0],
['Plus','TX',1,0],
['Small','MS',407,0],
['Medium','MS',3,0],
['Grand','MS',457,2],
['Elite','MS',20,0],
['Small','NC',557,0],
['Medium','NC',167,0],
['Plus','NC',95,1],
['Grand','NC',1090,5],
['Elite','NC',676,6],
['Lite','NM',1195,99],
['Small','NM',350,3],
['Medium','NM',212,0],
['Grand','NM',1509,8],
['Lite','NV',3899,389],
['Small','NV',147,0],
['Medium','NV',455,0],
['Plus','NV',1,1],
['Grand','NV',4100,16],
['Lite','OH',12,0],
['Small','OH',634,2],
['Medium','OH',749,0],
['Plus','OH',119,1],
['Grand','OH',3705,19],
['Elite','OH',3456,25],
['Small','PA',828,2],
['Medium','PA',288,0],
['Plus','PA',141,0],
['Grand','PA',2625,7],
['Elite','PA',1920,10],
['Small','SC',1146,2],
['Medium','SC',212,0],
['Plus','SC',223,4],
['Grand','SC',1803,6],
['Elite','SC',761,8],
['Small','TN',527,0],
['Medium','TN',90,0],
['Grand','TN',930,4],
['Elite','TN',395,1],
['Lite','ME',7232,58],
['Small','ME',1272,0],
['Medium','ME',1896,0],
['Plus','ME',1,0],
['Grand','ME',10782,33],
['Elite','ME',1911,3],
['Small','VA',495,0],
['Medium','VA',32,0],
['Plus','VA',7,0],
['Grand','VA',1557,12],
['Elite','VA',24,0],
['Small','WA',460,1],
['Plus','WA',88,3],
['Grand','WA',956,3],
['Small','WV',232,0],
['Medium','WV',71,0],
['Grand','WV',575,2],
['Elite','WV',368,3]
];
var color ={Elite:"#3366CC", Grand:"#DC3912",  Lite:"#FF9900", Medium:"#109618", Plus:"#990099", Small:"#0099C6"};
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 960).attr("height", 800);
svg.append("text").attr("x",250).attr("y",70)
    .attr("class","header").text("Sales Attempt");
svg.append("text").attr("x",750).attr("y",70)
    .attr("class","header").text("Sales");
var g =[svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(150,100)")
        ,svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(650,100)")];
var bp=[ viz.bP()
        .data(data)
        .min(12)
        .pad(1)
        .height(600)
        .width(200)
        .barSize(35)
        .fill(d=>color[d.primary])      
    ,viz.bP()
        .data(data)
        .value(d=>d[3])
        .min(12)
        .pad(1)
        .height(600)
        .width(200)
        .barSize(35)
        .fill(d=>color[d.primary])
];  
[0,1].forEach(function(i){
    g[i].call(bp[i])
    g[i].append("text").attr("x",-50).attr("y",-8).style("text-anchor","middle").text("Channel");
    g[i].append("text").attr("x", 250).attr("y",-8).style("text-anchor","middle").text("State");
    g[i].append("line").attr("x1",-100).attr("x2",0);
    g[i].append("line").attr("x1",200).attr("x2",300);
    g[i].append("line").attr("y1",610).attr("y2",610).attr("x1",-100).attr("x2",0);
    g[i].append("line").attr("y1",610).attr("y2",610).attr("x1",200).attr("x2",300);
    g[i].selectAll(".mainBars")
        .on("mouseover",mouseover)
        .on("mouseout",mouseout);
    g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").append("text").attr("class","label")
        .attr("x",d=>(d.part=="primary"? -30: 30))
        .attr("y",d=>+6)
        .text(d=>d.key)
        .attr("text-anchor",d=>(d.part=="primary"? "end": "start"));
    g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").append("text").attr("class","perc")
        .attr("x",d=>(d.part=="primary"? -100: 80))
        .attr("y",d=>+6)
        .text(function(d){ return d3.format("0.0%")(d.percent)})
        .attr("text-anchor",d=>(d.part=="primary"? "end": "start"));
});
function mouseover(d){
    [0,1].forEach(function(i){
        bp[i].mouseover(d);
        g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").select(".perc")
        .text(function(d){ return d3.format("0.0%")(d.percent)});
    });
}
function mouseout(d){
    [0,1].forEach(function(i){
        bp[i].mouseout(d);
        g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").select(".perc")
        .text(function(d){ return d3.format("0.0%")(d.percent)});
    });
}
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is your JS selector, you need to select `#content`. 
change 
    `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 960).attr("height", 800);`

to: 
    `var svg = d3.select("#content").append("svg").attr("width", 960).attr("height", 800);`
this will show your charts in desired area.

---

in order to center the charts you need to change the width and height:
`var svg = d3.select("#content").append("svg").attr("width", 600).attr("height", auto);`
then create a 
 
`<div id="mycenterdiv" style="text-align:center; width: 100%;"> </div>` 
 
in your wordpress page and then target that div (change the select)
`var svg = d3.select("#mycenterdiv").append("svg").attr("width", 600).attr("height", auto);`

Comment: Thank you!  That helped... kind of... it is still showing up just under the main content area.  I added "0123456789" to show the desired area.  I tried #main to no avail.  Worst case I can use #primary but not very desirable.

Comment: Also, any idea on how to center the entire chart?

Comment: Thank you, again.  Much appreciated!  However, #content is showing up in the same place as #primary, still under the main content (desired) area.  Mind boggling!

Comment: @KenWright , try `article div.entry-content` for selector, it will be right inside the post, and if you want to find selectors the easiest way is using `inspect`